# rbind data frames, duplicated rownames issue

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, rbind

While duplicated row (and column) names are allowed in a `matrix`, they are not allowed in a `data.frame`. Trying to `rbind()` some data frames having row names in common highlights this problem. Consider two data frames below:

```
foo = data.frame(a=1:3, b=5:7)
rownames(foo)=c("w","x","y")
bar = data.frame(a=c(2,4), b=c(6,8))
rownames(bar)=c("x","z")
# foo               bar
#   a b               a b
# w 1 5             x 2 6
# x 2 6             y 4 8
# y 3 7
```

Now trying to `rbind()` them (Pay attention to the row names):

```
rbind(foo, bar)
#    a b
# w  1 5
# x  2 6
# y  3 7
# x1 2 6
# z  4 8
```

But for the case of `matrix`:

```
rbind(as.matrix(foo), as.matrix(bar))
#   a b
# w 1 5
# x 2 6
# y 3 7
# x 2 6
# z 4 8
```

Here is the problem: How to `rbind()` two data frames, having duplicated rows (with the same row name) removed?

Comment: Duplicate row names are not allowed in data.frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
duprows <- which(!is.na(match(rownames(bar),rownames(foo))))
rbind(foo,bar[-duprows,])
```

?

Or (based on comments below)

```
duprows <- rownames(bar) %in% rownames(foo)
rbind(foo, bar[!duprows,])
```

Several variations are possible depending on (1) selected matched or unmatched; (2) finding numeric or logical values for the matches.

Comment: Nice! But is there any shorter solution? I like to think at the R problems as creative puzzles!

Comment: rbind(foo, bar[which(is.na(match(rownames(bar), rownames(foo)))),])

Comment: @AliSharifi -- `rbind(foo, bar[!rownames(bar) %in% rownames(foo),])` feels most natural to *me*.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Perfect! Why don't you make it as an answer?

Comment: @mplourde Very nice idea. It can be used with setNames().

Comment: `setdiff(rownames(bar), rownames(foo))` is one more of the numerous variations Ben alluded to...

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly what you're after, a nice, concise way to do this in one line of code:

```
unique(rbind(bar, foo))
#   a b
# x 2 6
# z 4 8
# w 1 5
# y 3 7
```

Comment: concise but *slightly* less efficient (since it binds the data frames and *then* throws away the duplicates)