# Merging dataframes in R with duplicated values in rownames

Tags: r

im trying to use the rbind function exactly like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038401/rbind-data-frames-duplicated-rownames-issue) post.

i have 3 dataframes with 2 columns (rownames and "source").

Between the first and second dataframes there are 2 rownames duplicated values and between the first and the third dataframes there's one.

a

`TMCS09g1008676 fleshy
TMCS09g1008677  fleshy
TMCS09g1008678  fleshy
TMCS09g1008679  fleshy
TMCS09g1008680  fleshy
TMCS09g1008681  fleshy
TMCS09g1008682  fleshy
TMCS09g1008683  fleshy`

b

`TMCS09g1008684 rotten
TMCS09g1008685  rotten
TMCS09g1008686  rotten
TMCS09g1008682  rotten
TMCS09g1008688  rotten
TMCS09g1008689  rotten
TMCS09g1008690  rotten
TMCS09g1008691  rotten
TMCS09g1008683  rotten
TMCS09g1008693  rotten`

c

`TMCS09g1008695 good
TMCS09g1008696  good
TMCS09g1008697  good
TMCS09g1008698  good
TMCS09g1008683  good
TMCS09g1008700  good
TMCS09g1008701  good
TMCS09g1008702  good
TMCS09g1008703  good
TMCS09g1008704  good
TMCS09g1008705  good`

after applying the fuction suggested in that post:

`duprows <- which(!is.na(match(rownames(a),rownames(b))))
rbind(a, b[-duprows,])`

i get this:
`> rbind(a, b[-duprows,])
               source
TMCS09g1008677 fleshy
TMCS09g1008678 fleshy
TMCS09g1008679 fleshy
TMCS09g1008680 fleshy
TMCS09g1008681 fleshy
TMCS09g1008682 fleshy
TMCS09g1008683 fleshy
8                <NA>
Warning message:
In`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

The main thing is that I would like to retain the 2nd column of the dataframe "a" for the duplicated values. How i was clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to understand the question.  Can you post some re-producible code, for example as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this.

Sample data (your data - reproducible ;)):

```
require(tidyverse)

a <- data.frame(ID = c("TMCS09g1008676",
          "TMCS09g1008677",
          "TMCS09g1008678",
          "TMCS09g1008679",
          "TMCS09g1008680" ,
          "TMCS09g1008681",
          "TMCS09g1008682",
          "TMCS09g1008683"), Staus = rep("fleshy"))

b <- data.frame(ID = c( "TMCS09g1008684" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008685" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008686" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008682"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008688" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008689" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008690" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008691",
                        "TMCS09g1008683" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008693"), Staus = rep("rotten"))

c <- data.frame(ID = c( "TMCS09g1008695" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008696"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008697" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008698"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008683"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008700" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008701"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008702" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008703"  ,
                        "TMCS09g1008704" ,
                        "TMCS09g1008705" ), Staus = rep("good"))
```

You can use `plyr::join_all` to do the matching. Because you have duplicated IDs it will be forced to open new columns to fit the duplicated values.

```
plyr::join_all(list(a,b,c), by = "ID")
```

Results:

```
              ID  Staus  Staus Staus
1 TMCS09g1008676 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
2 TMCS09g1008677 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
3 TMCS09g1008678 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
4 TMCS09g1008679 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
5 TMCS09g1008680 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
6 TMCS09g1008681 fleshy   <NA>  <NA>
7 TMCS09g1008682 fleshy rotten  <NA>
8 TMCS09g1008683 fleshy rotten  good
```